# Are Drow proficient in Drow's Poison?

Tags: dnd-5e, proficiency, poison, drow

Drow's poison are crafted only by drow, but if the drow dosen't have proficiency in poison kit, he still have proficiency in craft your poison?

Comment: Related: [How do Drow make poison?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132977/how-do-drow-make-poison)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "proficient in Drow's Poison". What does it mean to be "proficient in poison"?

Comment: nop, Drow's Poison is a special poison produced typically by a drow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Even if one race is what typically makes something, the entire race doesn't know how to make it

The text for [Drow Poison](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/drow-poison-injury) reads:

> This poison is typically made only by the drow

It says "typically". This shows that not only drow can make this. As such, it is not something specific to a property of the drow. As such, a drow do not have a natural innate ability to make this poison. As such, they would still need to be created by a Drow with the correct set of skills. This is further backed up by this line in the Monster Manual's section on Drow:

> *Poison Predilection*. Distilled from spider venom and the flora of the Underdark, poison can be found in abundance among the drow, and it plays an important part in their culture and politics. **Drow mages** concoct a viscid toxin that leaves enemies unconscious. Drow warriors coat their blades and crossbow bolts with this venom, looking forward to the interrogation and torture that follows combat.

(emphasis mine)

This further shows that even though this poison is common among the drow, only skilled drow, such as their Mages as referenced here, would know how to make this poison.

Answer (score 2):

### Not all Drow are capable of crafting poison.

From the Drow entry in the Monster Manual (emphasis mine):

> Poison Predilection. Distilled from spider venom and the flora of the Underdark, poison can be found in abundance among the drow... **Drow mages** concoct a viscid toxin that leaves enemies unconscious.

While it isn't called out specifically, this reference to drow mages in particular crafting poison suggests that the ability to create poison isn't a universally known skill, but rather one held by experts.